# Convert a String to binary sequence in C#

Tags: c#, string, binary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you convert a string to ascii to binary in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736533/how-do-you-convert-a-string-to-ascii-to-binary-in-c)

How to convert **string** such as `"Hello"` to **Binary** sequence as `1011010` ?

Comment: How does "Hello" become 1011010?

Comment: I am afraid the binary sequence of 'Hello' is not 1011010.

Comment: @Abdul, it could be, we just need to know the mapping algorithm.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen It's the "Super Hello String Compressor v0.1" :->

Comment: Yeah it could be but whats the mapping algo?

Comment: @Sudantha I'm sorry that you didn't understand the problem here. You need to tell us how you want to map the string to bits. Do you want the ascii encoding as a sequence of bits?

Comment: @Sudantha you should ask question with proper clarification so that people wont get confused about your question.

Comment: If the `Glyph` is A i need the `Binary` of it as `100 0000`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this:

```
string str = "Hello"; 
byte []arr = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
```

Comment: We would get only byte array through your code... but the query was "Convert a String to binary sequence in C#"

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer?

Answer (score 21):

```
string result = string.Empty;
foreach(char ch in yourString)
{
   result += Convert.ToString((int)ch,2);
}
```

this will translate `"Hello"` to `10010001100101110110011011001101111`

Comment: Your string is only 35 characters. You're missing a `.PadLeft(8, '0')` to your `.ToString()` call.

Answer (score 4):

```
string testString = "Hello";
UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
byte[] buf = encoding.GetBytes(testString);

StringBuilder binaryStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (byte b in buf)
{
    binaryStringBuilder.Append(Convert.ToString(b, 2));
}
Console.WriteLine(binaryStringBuilder.ToString());
```

Comment: Good one... This was the code i was searching....

Comment: How is this not the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use the BitConverter to get the bytes of the string and then format these bytes to their binary representation:

```
byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes( "Hello" );
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach ( byte b in bytes )
{
    sb.AppendFormat( "{0:B}", b );
}
string binary = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: -1: There is no overload for BitConverter.GetBytes that takes a string.

Comment: Thanks, I just found out myself. Changed the code snippet to use the Encoding.