# C# binary to string

Tags: c#, string, byte, bin

I am reading from serial port using `string messaga = _serialPort.ReadLine();`
When i `Console.WriteLine(messaga);` random characters appear on the screen which is logical because the binary data is non ASCII.
I suppose the method I am using handles data as ascii.
What i would like to do is create a string var and asign to it the binary raw data coming from the port so when I console.write this var I want to see a string with binary data like 1101101110001011010 and NOT characters. How can i manage that?

Comment: Do you have an example of the "characters" being displayed?

Comment: Did you really expect it to convert all the bits to a string of 10100010 etc?

Comment: Are we really here just for the reputation count?

Comment: Does `_serialPort` have a method for reading a `byte[]` vs a `String`?  It seems like you would be better off using that method instead if you want to print the bits.

Comment: We are not here for reputation,but we like to know is our solution correct or not!,and what is best solution to amend ourself

Comment: @Mike Miller - It's not the rep count itself, but there's a level of disrespect when someone helps you and there's no 'thank you' comment or acknowledgement (by upvote/marking as answer). From a practical POV, it makes it easier to scroll through posts and find out whether it contains an answer or not.

Comment: @keyboardP fair point and taken onboard.  I took a bit of umbrage in the tone of the comments i.e. get your affairs in order and then we bid you worthy of help.

Comment: @Mike Miller - Nothing like that :)- It's understandable when people are new here since it's quite different from 'normal' forums in that respect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
class Utility
{
  static readonly string[] BitPatterns ;
  static Utility()
  {
    BitPatterns = new string[256] ;
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 256 ; ++i )
    {
      char[] chars = new char[8] ;
      for ( byte j = 0 , mask = 0x80 ; mask != 0x00 ; ++j , mask >>= 1 )
      {
        chars[j] = ( 0 == (i&mask) ? '0' : '1' ) ;
      }
      BitPatterns[i] = new string( chars ) ;
    }
    return ;
  }

  const int BITS_PER_BYTE = 8 ;
  public static string ToBinaryRepresentation( byte[] bytes )
  {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( bytes.Length * BITS_PER_BYTE ) ;

    foreach ( byte b in bytes )
    {
      sb.Append( BitPatterns[b] ) ;
    }

    string instance = sb.ToString() ;
    return instance ;
  }

}
class Program
{
  static void Main()
  {
    byte[] foo = { 0x00 , 0x01 , 0x02 , 0x03 , } ;
    string s   = Utility.ToBinaryRepresentation( foo ) ;
    return ;
  }
}
```

Benchmarked this just now. The above code is approximately 12x faster than using `Convert.ToString()` and approximately 17x faster if the correction is added to pad with leading '0's.

Answer (score 5):

Stolen from [How do you convert a string to ascii to binary in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736533/how-do-you-convert-a-string-to-ascii-to-binary-in-c)

```
foreach (string letter in str.Select(c => Convert.ToString(c, 2)))
{
  Console.WriteLine(letter);
}
```

Comment: -1 for not getting it right. The results from `Convert.ToString(c,2)` aren't padded with leading zeros to the correct width for the type (e.g. conversion of `(byte)0x01` yields `"1"` rather than `"00000001"`).